# Firebase Notifications working strategy for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am working on a chat application and I have successfully integrated Firebase in my iOS app. And now, Firebase Notifications is not clear to me. I have setup everything properly as per the documentation, and now I am getting notification to my device when I send notification from the Firebase Console. I want to know how Firebase will handle or send notification to a particular user. Do we need to send device info to Firebase? Or how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem when dealing with FCM.

You need to set both data and notification objects in your message payload like it is described here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications

> **Messages with both notification and data payloads**
>
> App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification
>   and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background or
>   the foreground—essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of
>   receipt.
>
> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the
>   notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps
>   on the notification. When in the foreground, your app receives a
>   message object with both payloads available. Here is a JSON-formatted
>   message containing both the notification key and the data key:

```
{
  "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
  },
  "data" : {
    "Nick" : "Mario",
    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
  }   
}
```

Also, you need to set high priority if you want to deliver push notifications on the device.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

> **Setting the priority of a message**
>
> You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream
>   messages: normal and high priority. Delivery of normal and high
>   priority messages works like this:
>
> **Normal priority**. This is the default priority for message delivery.
>   Normal priority messages won't open network connections on a sleeping
>   device, and their delivery may be delayed to conserve the battery. For
>   less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email or
>   other data to sync, choose normal delivery priority.
>
> **High priority**
>   FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing
>   the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a
>   network connection to your app server. Apps with instant messaging,
>   chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally need to open a
>   network connection and make sure FCM delivers the message to the
>   device without delay. Set high priority only if the message is
>   time-critical and requires the user's immediate interaction, but
>   beware that setting your messages to high priority contributes more to
>   battery drain compared with normal priority messages. Valid values are
>   normal and high. For more details, see the server reference for HTTP
>   or XMPP.
>
> For iOS client apps, normal and high priority are analogous to APNs
>   priority levels 5 and 10. For full details on iOS-specific behavior,
>   see the APNs documentation. For details on Android-specific behavior,
>   see Optimizing for Doze and App Standby.
>
> Here is an example of a normal priority message to notify a magazine
>   subscriber that new content is available to download:

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new"
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}
```

You don't need to send anything to Firebase if you have successfully configured your project for Firebase.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: Hello@Anuj Thanks For the comment and  i understood like this i need to send NOTIFICATION payload when am send the text message to a user simultaneously so based on the UID fire base will send Notification  is this is  the Way

Comment: Exactly, you need to send both the data and notification objects in a single message and refer it using Firebase ID. The device token gets stored on Firebase automatically. If your app is in background the notification will be shown. Make sure the message priority is high

Comment: Awesome Bro  i got it and can u tell me the Method In IOS  to send the Data and Notification payload  togeather   As of now am sending only Message  from My app and what would the method

Comment: You'll need a web application to handle this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream

Comment: @anju  web application? i didnt get this firebase will cache and it will deliver the notification when the user  has a active connection  Right !  what is the requirement of this web application and how would connection or communication will be there between both web application or web server and the Fire Base Server ! and is it manadatory or firebase can manage the upstream  and downstream  notifcations

Comment: Firebase acts as a mediator to deliver messages to the clients. Your web application will know to which device you need to send messages on. When you register for push notifications on the client, Firebase will also configure itself and generate a token which will should be stored on your application server to identify the users. You can only deliver upstream messages from client to another client directly only if you know their Firebase tokens which is not possible if you don't store them anywhere which is accessible to both clients.

Comment: Web application  Means  backend for the IOS app (API s Server) Right and  web application  can know the user details to whom it should  send the notification( If we setup for Push Notifications) but how come it(web server or web application) know about the message    that fire base received  so it should deliver the Notification  some user has send this  this Hi or some thing. do we need to set up firebase Url in Web application or how.

Comment: Hello anuj    chat app developed in andriod and ios with different data base in firebase how to match the or make the database to one  as common for both andriod and ios

Comment: You should probably ask a new question. Firebase and Web backend side of stuff is out of scope for this question

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to know how Firebase will handle or send notification to a particular user.*

The Firebase Server acts as a ***middle-man*** that handles the queuing of your messages.

For example, for **Downstream Messaging**, you send a push notification from your App Server or using the Firebase Console, the message is delivered to the FCM Server, storing it until such time that the device it has to send it to is available to receive it (or until such time you want it to be delivered, see [Lifetime of a Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime)).

You can check out this [Lifecycle Flow](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#lifecycle) of GCM (since I think for this part, it's still the same for FCM):

> **Lifecycle Flow**
>
> - Send and receive downstream messages.
>
>   - Send a message. The app server sends messages to the client app:
>
>     1. The app server sends a message to GCM connection servers.
>     2. The GCM connection server enqueues and stores the message if the device is offline.
>     3. When the device is online, the GCM connection server sends the message to the device.
>     4. On the device, the client app receives the message according to the platform-specific implementation. See your platform-specific documentation for details.
>   - Receive a message. A client app receives a message from a GCM connection server.

Note that this the one I mentioned is only for *Downstream Messaging*. You can check out the docs if you're also interested to learn about the flow for *Upstream Messaging*.

---

> *Do we need to send device info to Firebase?*

It depends on your use-case. Although I think it is highly advisable for you to store all the registration tokens for future use.

---

> *Or how does it work?*

Besides from what I already mentioned above, I'm  just gonna go ahead and quote the [How does it work?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#how_does_it_work) from the official docs:

> **How does it work?**
>
> An FCM implementation includes an app server that interacts with FCM via HTTP or XMPP protocol, and a client app. You can compose and send messages using the app server or the [Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) console.
>
> Firebase Notifications is built on Firebase Cloud Messaging and shares the same FCM SDK for client development. For testing or for sending marketing or engagement messages with powerful built-in targeting and analytics, you can use Notifications. For deployments with more complex messaging requirements, FCM is the right choice.